# How to set two RabbitMQ connections for the same Camel RouteBuilder configure method

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

I want listen FROM rabbit queue, process, and post message TO another rabbit queue. I'm not working with spring. The messages are duplicated in this configuration.

This is a short code:

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("rabbitmq://localhost/B?autoDelete=false&queue=worker&threadPoolSize=1&autoAck=false").
                    log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message ${id}").
                    to("rabbitmq://localhost/B?autoDelete=false&queue=processed");
        }
    });
```

I have tried this too:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

    com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory connectionFactoryWorker = new ConnectionFactory();
    com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory connectionFactoryProcessed = new ConnectionFactory();
    org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
    String camelBeanNameWorker = "connectionFactoryWorker";
    String camelBeanNameProcessed = "connectionFactoryProcessed";
    registry.put(camelBeanNameWorker, connectionFactoryWorker);
    registry.put(camelBeanNameProcessed, connectionFactoryProcessed);
    context.setRegistry(registry);

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("rabbitmq://localhost/B?connectionFactory=connectionFactoryWorker&autoDelete=false&queue=worker&threadPoolSize=1&autoAck=false").
                    log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message ${id}").
                    to("rabbitmq://localhost/B?connectionFactory=connectionFactoryProcessed&autoDelete=false&queue=processed");
        }
    });

    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000l);
    context.stop();
}
```

Worker queue start in four messages, but Messages are re-queued:

> 561 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-2 
>   566 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-4 
>   566 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-6 
>   567 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-8 
>   568 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-10 
>   571 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-12 
>   572 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-14 
>   572 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-16 
>   573 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-18 
>   574 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-20 
>   574 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-22 
>   575 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-24 
>   576 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-26 
>   576 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-28 
>   577 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-30 
>   578 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-32 
>   578 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-34 
>   ... 
>       64k after 
>   ... 
>   10561 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-128690 
>   10561 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-128692 
>   10561 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-128694 
>   10561 Message ID-host-1510600494291-0-128696

Comment: You posted the code what you tried, but haven't told the outcome. what is outcome of what you tried? what's the issue you are getting?

Comment: What Camel version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Camel 2.20.0

Comment: Messages are processed in a loop. They are re-queued and reprocessed until the program closes. I updated with log output

Comment: Any updates on this?  I am having the same scenario happen to me

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, without knowing the outcome, I noticed that you are missing that you are missing the "#" when you are trying to use a bean from the registry.

What you need to do when using something from registry is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
DefaultCamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
String beanNameWorker = "connectionFactoryWorker";
String beanNameProcessed = "connectionFactoryProcessed";
registry.put(beanNameWorker, connectionFactory);
registry.put(beanNameProcessed, connectionFactory);
context.setRegistry(registry);

context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("rabbitmq://localhost/B?connectionFactory=#connectionFactoryWorker&autoDelete=false&queue=worker&threadPoolSize=1&autoAck=false").
                log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message ${id}").
                to("rabbitmq://localhost/B?connectionFactory=#connectionFactoryProcessed&autoDelete=false&queue=processed");
    }
});
```

}

By the way what is the actual outcome? what errors do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have found your answer in another question

[Infinite loop in Camel - Rabbit MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475236/infinite-loop-in-camel-rabbit-mq)

Apparently setting BridgeEnpoint=false option stops this.  Without specifying this the EXCHANGE_NAME and ROUTING_KEY headers are taken from the received message overriding whatever you might have specified in the "to" configuration.  For example...

`rabbitmq://localhost/B?connectionFactory=connectionFactoryProcessed&autoDelete=false&queue=processed&BridgeEndpoint=false`

Comment: Can you outline why it does not?

Comment: This has nothing to do with spring.  It is a setting in the camel-rabbitmq component itself.    So the url you would specify in the camel "to" method would contain this setting.  See my edits above